# How to set volumn slider in phaser js?

Tags: phaser-framework

How to set volumn slider in phaser js?
like this showing below image and also tell me how to set defult value of the slider if i change screen slider value become zero.

[image]

```
 var print2;
    this.rexUI.add.slider({
            x: 400,
            y: 230,
            width: 200,
            height: 30,
            orientation: 'x',

            track: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 10, COLOR_DARK),
            indicator: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 10, COLOR_PRIMARY),
            thumb: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 10, COLOR_PRIMARY),

            input: 'click', // 'drag'|'click'
            easeValue: { duration: 250 },

            valuechangeCallback: function(value) {
                value *= 10
                value = Math.floor(value * 10)
                print2 = value;

                console.log(print2);
            },

        })
        .layout();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for setting the default - **value** of the slider, you just need to add the `value` property.

```
let slider = this.rexUI.add.slider({
    ...
    value: .5 // default vaule
    ...
});
```

to set the slider value later, just set `slider.value = .5;`

Here the [link to the documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/slider/)

Setting the volume for *Phaser Audio*:

```
let sound = this.sound.add('sound');
sound.play({loop: true });
...
let slider = this.rexUI.add.slider({
    ...
    valuechangeCallback: function(value){
        sound.volume = value; // set volume between 0 - 1
    }
    ...
});
```

Here a link to an offical demo: [link to demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/audio/html5-audio/volume-mute-rate-detune)